# Are there any tools to check my web's design in HTML and CSS in all browsers?

Tags: html, css

To check if my web is running correctly in all browsers I have to open them.

Are there any tools or websites which could help me achieve it easier?

Comment: Do you want to check functionality or just a screen shot to show that it is working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my favorite by far is Adobe's Browser Lab

https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html

check your site in all browsers and multiple versions of: chrome, safari, IE, FF

Comment: Browser labs is WAY better than browsershots because it's instantaneous.  The last time I used browsershots there was a 48 hour wait to get access to shots for certain browser combinations.

Answer (score 1):

[Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) is definetly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I dont know any, I wish I did!

Though most of the time the problem is Internet Explorer and his strange behaviors changing from version to version, there is [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) which let you try on multiple IE version at the same time. Pretty useful!

I just found http://browsershots.org/ that seems pretty good and solid, I had neverheard of this before, I'll give it a shot and suggest you to do so!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to see screen-shots without interactivity, browsershots.org is a good starting point.

There are other solutions that you can automate, but they cost money, so start with Browser Shots and see how you get on.